# Wordpress get_object_taxonomies() For Woocommerce product inside plugin is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the taxonomies for the woocommerce post type (product) inside a plugin in the wordpress backend and it gives me back an empty array.

Works fine with posts though, but it doesn't work with woocommerce custom post type.

Also the code is working inside the posts.

Here is my code :

```
global $product;
$option_tax_types_obj = get_object_taxonomies($product, 'objects');

$option_tax_types_obj = get_object_taxonomies('product', 'objects');
```

And also tried it with

```
global $woocommerce;
```

still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where are you calling this?

Comment: I'm calling it in a plugin.Not inside a loop or anything.

Comment: I've tried your code on wp_head action and it works... can you include more of what you are doing? I'm not sure how to reproduce your problem

Comment: I'm trying to check for the taxonomies inside a plugin.

Comment: The plugin just simply can't check for the woocommerce product type.

Comment: I also tried applying global $woocommerce but still the plugin in the backend can't get the taxonomies, however in the frontend the same code can easily get the taxonomies like you mentioned

Comment: Still, I tried hooking it to init like `add_action('init','get_product_taxonomies');` and inside the function is `$option_tax_types_obj = get_object_taxonomies('product', 'objects'); print_r( $option_tax_types_obj );`. it works...

Comment: I tried it from a different file than the main one and it is working, but in the main one with the author info and everything it's still not working

Comment: it depends on the hook... maybe it was running too early..

Comment: The woocommerce class is not loading in the main plugin file. However it is running in any other file

Comment: it's running too early then... maybe it's running before woo... find a way to make it run after woo is loaded